# How do I send a string to master using i2c

Tags: i2c, string

I want to write an Arduino program that simply recieves a string (via the I2C wire library) from a master Arduino, then waits for a request, and sends that string back.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4); 
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); 
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

String data = "";

void loop()
{

}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  data = "";
  while( Wire.available()){
    data += (char)Wire.read();
  }
}

void requestEvent()
{
    Wire.write(data);
}
```

I read in the API that the write() function accepts a string, but I keep getting a "No matching function for call" error.  I tried to simply replace

```
Wire.write(data);
```

with

```
Wire.write("test");
```

and that worked without error.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Try this instead of wire.write(data); wire.print(data);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`data` is a [`String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject). `"test"` is a [`char*`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/string). [`Wire.write()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireWrite) has no prototype that takes a `String`.

```
Wire.write(data.c_str());
```

Comment: working perfectly :)